# How do I modify a yaml field in go when I don't know every possible field in the yaml?

Tags: go, yaml

How can I modify a field in yaml when I don't know every possible field the yaml can have? I can't define a struct that has every possible field, and `gopkg.in/yaml.v2` `Unmarshall` ignores fields that are not in the supplied struct, so `Marshall` loses any fields not in the struct, which is unacceptable.

Is there a package that will allow me to dynamically specify a field name that will either return a basic value or struct if the field exists and nil/err otherwise? And marshall my changes out while preserving  all other fields from the input yaml?

Thanks, Paul

Comment: Use a `map` if you don't know the keys ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me to any example that preserves arbitrarily complex yaml? The examples I've seen have specific maps for specific yaml.


This is particularly relevant for Kubernetes where a core programming technique is getting resource yaml (often complex, often poorly documented), updating some field(s), and then applying the modified yaml. I'm porting function currently implemented in Javascript (yaml converted to JSON) where dynamically accessing fields and preserving all input fields is just built in to the language. I'm trying to consolidate some bash and javascript to go.

Comment: this is [YAML-to-go generator](https://mengzhuo.github.io/yaml-to-go/) is a good on-line resource for building `go` compatible structs given sample input `YAML`.

Comment: I just posted an answer based on what I think your source YAML looks like...

Answer (score 3):

Unmarshalling with `map[interface{}]interface{}` did the trick:

```golang
            wcc := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
            err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(wccString), &wcc)
```

The  notation to access the yaml structure is not intuitive (to me), but I did eventually find an incantation that works:

```golang
wcc["extensions"].(map[interface{}]interface{})["scriptURLs"].([]interface{})[2] = "https://192.168.0.3:8080/..."
```

Answer (score 1):

Guessing what your YAML looks like based on your answer, perhaps something like this would work:

```
//
// a map (string index) of map (string index) of a string slice
//
type mystruct map[string]map[string][]string

//
// guessing what your YAML looks like:
//
wccYAML = `
extensions:
  scriptURLs:
    - 'https://localhost:9000'
    - 'https://localhost:9001'
    - 'https://localhost:9002'
`
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/wvkr2pFk-0j

Generally one wants to avoid using `interface{}` as you have seen the casting gets messy very quickly.